# Does "Custom Field Template" plugin have an auto-unpublish feature?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-fields

On a client site that I didn't help build but am currently doing maintenance on, they are using the "Custom Field Template" plugin to set dates for their posts in the events category. This is their template content:

[Event Date] 
type=textfield 
date=true 
dateFormat = yyyy/mm/dd 
startDate = '1986/10/12'

Currently, they are having issues with their event posts not unpublishing after the event date has passed. According to my supervisor, the event posts used to unpublish automatically by themselves once the event date passed, but now it is not doing it anymore. I looked at the other plugins that they have installed, but none of them are related to unpublishing posts. I was wondering if "Custom Field Template" had auto-unpublish settings, or there is some code I need to insert somewhere to handle what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, CFT doesn't have that function. We have used the [Content Scheduler plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-scheduler/) in the past in conjunction with CFT. That might be an option for you. Good luck.